Cannot Install Windows Onto TUF F15 (2023) FX507VI
I attempted to install windows 11 onto my TUF F15 laptop from a flash-drive, but when I went through the install process, the 1 terrabyte SSD inside the laptop did not appear in the list of drives. I then installed a second 500 gigabyte SSD and transferred the contents of the bootable flash-drive into the second SSD to try and install windows through the SSD, but the windows boot option did not appear in the BIOS, but the BIOS is able to reconize bootable linux installations on the Second SSD. Both drives are Samsung SSDs and they are in perfect working condition installed correctly. I think that I may need some . I can't figure out how to get windows onto my laptop, thanks.

Windows 11 strictly requires GPT.

"the 1 terrabyte SSD inside the laptop did not appear in the list of drives." - This suggests the disk had partitions.  So did you make sure to boot the system with CSM disabled?  Additionally, is the disk MBR or GPT? Be sure to [edit] your question with enough information to diagnose your issue. Make sure you are booting the installation mode in UEFI mode, this likely will require you to disable CSM mode, to ensure it does not attempt to be in an incompatible mode with Windows 11.

The issue is probably not your install media. Focus on the "can't see the drive" bit. There are a few questions on this site that are very similar that I recall seeing within the past few months. I would guess there are guides online about this too. So, what research have you done regarding this?
